# Node.js - How to write/serialize an arbitrary JavaScript object that contains functions and special values and save it to a .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, persistence, writefile

I have a JavaScript object that contains functions and special values like `Infinity`, as well as strings and numbers:

```
const myObject = {
   propertyA: "my string",
   propertyB: 5,
   propertyC: () => "function returing a string",
   propertyD: Infinity
};
```

I would like to save it to a file so that the resulting content looks like this:

```
export default function () {
    return {
        propertyA: "my string",
        propertyB: 5,
        propertyC: () => "function returing a string",
        propertyD: Infinity
    };
}
```

I have tried to use `JSON.stringify()`, but that doesn't work with functions and special values, as those are not valid JSON:

```
writeFileSync('my-output.js', `
   export default function () {
       return ${ JSON.stringify(myObject) };
   }
`);
```

```js
const myObject = {
   propertyA: "my string",
   propertyB: 5,
   propertyC: () => "function returing a string",
   propertyD: Infinity
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 4));
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: in what case json.stringify not working?

Comment: JSON only holds value properties, not functions.

Comment: Indeed, functions are not valid JSON but it still valid javascript object and I want to write a javascript file ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different way to serialize your object other than `JSON.stringify`, maybe something like this:

```js
// Pretty:

const TAB = '    ';
const BR = '\n';
const CBR = `,${ BR }`;

// Minified: 

// const TAB = '';
// const BR = '';
// const CBR = ',';

function arrayAsString(arr, depth=0) {
  const _ = TAB.repeat(depth - 1);
  const __ = _ + TAB;
  
  return `[${
    BR }${ arr.map(value =>
    `${ __ }${ serialize(value, depth) }`).join(CBR) }${
    BR }${ _ }]`;
}

function objectAsString(obj, depth=0) {
  const _ = TAB.repeat(depth - 1);
  const __ = _ + TAB;
  
  return `{${
    BR }${ Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) =>
    `${ __ }${ key }: ${ serialize(value, depth) }`).join(CBR) }${
    BR }${ _ }}`;
}

function serialize(value, depth=0) {
  if (value === null) {
    return `${ value }`;
  } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return arrayAsString(value, depth + 1);
  } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
    return objectAsString(value, depth + 1);
  } else if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return `"${ value }"`;
  } else {
    return `${ value }`;
  }
}

const notStringifyableObject = {
  1: Infinity,
  str: "my string",
  num: 5,
  func: () => console.log('It works! '),
  mixArr: [{
    value: 1
  }, {
    value: 2
  }, 1, 2, [3, 4, 5]],
  arr: [1, 2, 3],
  obj: { foo: 'bar' },
  nil: null,
  und: undefined
};

const serialized = serialize(notStringifyableObject);

// This is what you would save in a file:
console.log(`export default ${ serialized };`);

// Check if it's actually working: 

eval(`test = ${ serialized }`);

test.func();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

Then, once you have serialized your object, you can save its `string` representation to a file with some additional code so that you can later load it using `require`, as you have already done:

```
writeFileSync('my-output.js', `export default () => ${ serialized };`);
```

Or:

```
writeFileSync('my-output.js', `export default ${ serialized };`);
```

Note that's just a basic implementation and it doesn't support regular expression, dates, circular structures... So you might prefer to use a library like [`serialize-javascript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript) or [`serialize-to-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-to-js) instead of implementing your own solution.

Comment: it crash when a value is null

Comment: @JoG Fixed. That's because `typeof null` is `"object"`, so there should be a condition that checks and handles that inside `serialize()`.